# Templates and friends

Tags: c++

While reading from Thinking in C++ Volume 2, from the Templates in Depth chapter, I see that if you have a friendly function in a template class, you need to forward declaration that function. I made this example to test this, overlaoding the output operator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*
template<class T>
class X;
template<class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const X<T>& x);
*/
template<class T>
class X {
    T t;
public:
    X(T i): t(i) {}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const X<T>& x)
        {
            return os << x.t;
        }
};


int main()
{
    X<int> a(1);
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

But it works without the forward declaration, but then I test it with the definition of << outside of the class:

```
friend ostream& operator << <>(ostream& os, const X<T>& x); (inside of the class)

template<class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const X<T>& x)
{
        return os << x.t;
}
```

I am not sure why with the definition inside of the class it doesnt apply, is it because you have to explicit say that the ostream operator function is a template ? (using <> ) ??

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The C++FAQ Lite has a chapter on this too: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16

Comment: @ Cubbi: ohh, so when i define it inside of the class, there is no need for forward declaration, perfect explination, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that my comment was satisfactory, here it is in form of an answer.

The C++FAQ Lite has [a chapter on this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.16), which, for the sake of completeness, boils down to two possible ways to convince the compiler while it is examining the body of the class X that the friend function `operator<<` is actually a function template.

One approach is, as you did, declare the function template `operator<<` before the class definition and use the `<>` in the friend line inside the class body, giving the remarkable syntax of `operator << <>(`.

The other approach is to define the entire body of the friend template function inside the body of class X, which makes the forward declaration unnecessary.